# JScrollPane not Scrolling when text overflows

Tags: java, scrollpane

I made a JScrollPane and put a JTextArea in it. Then I added the ScrollPane to the frame. That works fine. However, When text overflows off the JTextArea, the ScrollPane will not scroll at all. Please help. Ive included a picture (The picture shows that there is text off the pane, but I cant see it, so im trying to scroll down, but its now allowing me to).

```
JTextArea console = new JTextArea(35, 70);
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(console, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

[image]

Comment: You're not messing with either components preferred sizes?

Comment: i have the perferred sizze of the textarea matching the size of teh scrollpane, and ive tried others, but nothing seems to work

Comment: The don't (set the preferred size of the `JTextArea`), this is what the scroll pane is using to determine if the text area is exceeding the size of the viewable area